# Смена раскладки на linux через python

Tags: python, linux

Собственно как это делать на Windows в интернете решение [есть](http://blog.dzinko.org/2010/11/windows.html), но вот как сменить на linux ?

Comment: Я не знаком с linux, но может просто вызвать setxkbmap?

Comment: @jfs, *Некоторые люди и android считают linux-ом* — всё верно: программа *linux* используется? значит, тоже «linux». // по крайней мере: операционная систем *android* (если это можно, конечно, назвать операционной системой) имеет к программе *linux* ничуть не меньшее отношение, чем любой дистрибутив операционной системы *gnu/linux*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот я тормоз...Если `xdo.Xdo().send_keysequence_window(xdo.CURRENTWINDOW, b"alt+shift")` не работает и если я уже пользуюсь pyautogui,то неужели было трудно додуматься до такого ???

```
import pyautogui as pikapika #pip install pyautogui
pikapika.hotkey('shift', 'alt')
```

Answer (score 3):

Проблема с Linux заключается в том, что существует довольно большое множество всевозможных переключателей раскладок и для разных устройств раскладка переключается по-разному. Вот, например, вызов такой команды из терминала приводит к включению раскладки Эсперанто у меня в GNOME с Unity.

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/current 'uint32 2'
```

Точнее говоря, это приводит к установке в качестве текущего источника ввода третьего по счёту (если считать с 1). А сам список этих источников можно получить вот такой командой.

```
dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/sources
```

*Напечатает:*

> ```
> [('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'ru'), ('xkb', 'epo'), ('xkb', 'ua')]
> ```

<sup>В системе используются четыре раскладки.</sup>

Таким образом, для переключения текущей раскладки алгоритм такой:

1. Прочитать и запомнить значение ключа `/org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/current`.
2. Прочитать значение ключа `/org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/sources`, чтобы выяснить количество используемых источников ввода (т.е раскладок).
3. Затем прибавить единицу к номеру текущей раскладки по модулю количества раскладок.
4. Записать полученное значение в ключ `/org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/current`.

Насколько я понял, интерфейса для взаимодействия с БД dconf чисто через Python нету, поэтому придётся вызывать упомянутую выше консольную утилиту и разбирать её вывод. Впрочем, это уже отдельная тема.

Comment: *алгоритм такой* — мне кажется, всё-таки первым пунктом должно быть выяснение — действительно ли используется исковерканный gnome-овцами x-сервер. потому что актуально это **только** для x-сервера, исковерканного подобным образом.

Answer (score 1):

Среди множества множества вариантов, можно попробовать [`python-libxdo`](https://rshk.github.io/python-libxdo/library.html#xdo.Xdo):

```
import xdo  # $ pip install  python-libxdo
xdo.Xdo().send_keysequence_window(xdo.CURRENTWINDOW, b"super+space")
```

Это выполняет аналог консольной команды [`xdotool`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xdotool.1.html):

```
$ xdotool key super+space
```

<kbd>Super + Space</kbd> клавиши меняют раскладку на моей машине. В другом контексте что-то другое может работать.

Comment: @stackflow: Библиотека работает на Python 3.5. И shift+alt также работает (вероятно на `Shift_L+Meta_L` отображается). *"Чёт не меняется раскладка."* -- мало информативно: что конкретно происходит? К примеру, если у вас X не запущен, или `$DISPLAY` не настроен, текущего GUI окна нет, то команда завершится с ошибкой. Видите ли вы ошибку?

Comment: @stackflow: что у вас `xdpyinfo | grep XTEST` возвращает?

Comment: @stackflow: где вы запускаете `python`? Попробуйте больше информации предоставить (по капле, чтобы не выдавливать -- посмотрите на мои комментарии: если я упомянул "дистрибутив Linux", то напишите, что вы используете в вопросе, если я упомянул `$DISPLAY`, приведите значение -- для этого способа это не обязательно, но может для других методов иметь значение). Не относится к проблеме, но упомяните в вопросе контекст задачи (вы понимаете, что вы можете программно любые Юникодные символы (русские, китайские, итд) использовать вне зависимости от текущей раскладки?)