# Как передавать нажатие клавиш в субпроцесс

Tags: python, subprocess, pyautogui

Вопрос - в теме. Нажатие клавиш (в том числе функциональных) можно создавать используя модуль, например, `pyautogui`. Но они срабатывают для верхнего активного окна как я понял.

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.press('f5')
```

А хотелось бы "распихивать" нажатые клавиши по подпроцессам...
Подпроцесс - это powerpoint
Как это можно сделать?

Comment: стоит упомянуть, что речь идёт о GUI приложениях (судя [по предыдущему вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/745275/23044)), а не о передаче ввода через stdin консольного приложения.

Comment: pyautogui заменяет клавиатуру, мышку. pyautogui в отличии от pywinauto не умеет искать приложения, окошки в них. На X, [можно xdotool использовать](https://goo.gl/Hddcwb), чтобы найти окошко и активировать. Пример посылки клавиш с [помощью xdo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/704147/23044)

Comment: ну круто, только в pywinauto пример с их сайта со строкой
# Click on a button
app.AboutNotepad.OK.click()
не работает ))) не находит в словаре ОК....